# inserting selected text file data into jtable

Tags: java, ide, text-files

Text file data

> ```
> 01/Test1/1/Admin
>
> 02/Test2/1/Customer
>
> 03/Test3/1/Manager
>
> 04/Test4/1/Manager
> ```

Above is the way data is been stored in my text file.

so now I want to display the data in jtable but I only want the line which has Manager option.

Below attached is my code

```
DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

 try
 {  String search3 = ManagerSearch.getText().toString();

    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sort = new TableRowSorter<>(table);
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sort);
    sort.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search3));

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("managerinfo.txt"));
     String reader;

     while ((reader = br.readLine())!=null){
         table.addRow(reader.split("\\|"));
     }
     br.close();
     View.setEnabled(false);
     Search.setEnabled(false);
 }
 catch (Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e+" ");
 }
```

Comment: Can you say a little more about what's going wrong?  Do you have an idea of where you might change your code to do this filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add contains check for reader as follows:

```
DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

 try
 {  String search3 = ManagerSearch.getText().toString();

    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sort = new TableRowSorter<>(table);
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sort);
    sort.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search3));

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("managerinfo.txt"));
     String reader;

     while ((reader = br.readLine())!=null){
       if(reader.contains("Manager")){  
        table.addRow(reader.split("\\|"));
      }
     }
     br.close();
     View.setEnabled(false);
     Search.setEnabled(false);
 }
 catch (Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e+" ");
 }
```